# Error "No module named MySQLdb" on docker

Tags: docker, ssh, containers, dockerfile

I am trying to connect my docker app container to a local mysql but I get an error that "No module named MySQLdb". My config.py file is:

```
import os
BASEDIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO = os.path.join(BASEDIR, 'db_repository')

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'mysql+mysqldb://root:@192.168.0.29/test'
DEBUG = True
```

And my docker file is:

```
FROM python:2.7-slim

WORKDIR /app

ADD . /app

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 9999

ENV NAME flaskCrudAPI

CMD ["python", "run.py"]
```

My requirements.txt file contains this content:

```
virtualenv
flask
mysql-server
flask_sqlalchemy
flask_migrate
sqlalchemy
```

I am running the app using this command:

```
docker run -p 9999:9999 flaskcrud
```

But I am getting this error about mysqldb module not found. I have tried adding python-mysql and a number of other packages to the requirements.txt file but with that, even the build of the container fails at the installation command. What am I doing wrong? Or what should I do?

Comment: Are you able to connect with command line ? like `mysql -h $ip -u root -p`

Comment: yes, I'm connected there

Comment: Can you please share the detailed logs for `docker build $image_name` is `pip install` commands install packages from internet ?

Comment: yes, `pip install` installs packages from internet. And the build throws no error if there is no mysql client ( "MySQL-python" for instance) mentioned in the requirements. Or do you want me to include those and then show you the logs?

Comment: When the build is successful and I try to POST data using the API I have created, I get the error I have mentioned above.

Comment: for instance, this is the error I get when I add "mysql-server" to the requirements.txt file:  "_Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mysql-server (from -r requirements.txt (line 3)) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for mysql-server (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))_ "

Comment: if possible than show the logs for `docker build $image_name` and `pip install`,other packages except `mysql`  able to install from internet ?

Comment: everything installs perfectly fine except the mysql packages

Comment: here is the log from the `docker build $image_name` command: https://www.dropbox.com/s/u4fvos8z52d9mwy/Screenshot%202017-04-24%2017.23.37.png?dl=0

Comment: Are you able to execute same program outside docker ??

Comment: yes, everything works fine outside docker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error with the requirements.txt file. I used proper versions for all the dependencies listed in the file and I was able to install mysql-python without an errors.

Another problem that seemed to be occurring was the python version. I was using the slimmed version of python which happened to be causing the issue as well. I changed `python:2.7-slim` to just `python:2.7` and I was able to resolve the issue.

I hope this helps